# looping through sliced list and match elements with dict values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matching

I have generated a survey in python, now I have a list of answers, which I want to match with a dictionary containing the evaluation keys.

I do not achieve to iterate through the list (answers_all), take an element match it with the dictionary (eval_keys) values and print the key associated with the value.

Here is the python code:

```
import random
def rand_participant(n):
    #generate a single random participant
    age = random.randint(28,35)
    gender = random.choice(['male', 'female'])
    return int(age), str(gender)

#generate a list of 100 random participants
sample_probe = [rand_participant(1) for _ in range(101)]


def rand_answer(x):
    #create a single random answer 
    f = random.randint(1,5)
    q = random.randint(1,5)
    return int(f), int(q)

def participant_answer(y): 
    # create all 6 random answers
    all_answer = [rand_answer(1) for blu in range(6)]
    return all_answer

def survey_res(a):
    # create set of random survery results
    result = [participant_answer(1) for bla in range(101)]
    return result

my_survey = list(zip(sample_probe, survey_res()))
answer_all = list(survey_res(1))


answer_all = 
[[(3, 2), (5, 5), (1, 5), (5, 5), (5, 1), (5, 5)],
 [(4, 3), (1, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (1, 1), (4, 1)],
 [(2, 1), (4, 1), (5, 2), (2, 3), (4, 1), (3, 2)],
 [(3, 4), (1, 1), (1, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (1, 1)],
 [(1, 2), (3, 3), (4, 3), (2, 4), (1, 3), (1, 1)],
 [(3, 1), (5, 5), (4, 4), (2, 5), (2, 3), (3, 3)],
 [(2, 3), (4, 1), (3, 1), (5, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)],
 [(3, 4), (4, 2), (5, 2), (5, 5), (1, 1), (4, 4)],
 [(5, 5), (5, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (2, 2), (4, 1)],
 [(4, 1), (1, 1), (3, 1), (3, 4), (4, 5), (1, 4)],
 [(2, 1), (5, 3), (2, 2), (1, 4), (3, 1), (5, 1)],
 [(2, 1), (3, 5), (3, 4), (4, 3), (4, 2), (3, 1)],
 [(5, 3), (1, 2), (2, 5), (4, 5), (3, 1), (5, 3)]
...
]

eval_keys = {
    "Q": (1,1), "A": (1,2), "A": (1,3), "A": (1,4), "P": (1,5),
    "R": (2,1), "Q": (2,2), "I": (2,3), "I": (2,4), "M": (2,5),
    "R": (3,1), "I": (3,2), "I": (3,3), "I": (3,4), "M": (3,5),
    "R": (4,1), "I": (4,2), "I": (4,3), "Q": (4,4), "M": (4,5),
    "R": (5,1), "R": (5,2), "R": (5,3), "R": (5,4), "Q": (5,5)
}
```

Each row of the list is the answer of a single participant. Therefore the output should be 6 letters (like "R" or "Q" etc.) for each row in the list.

Comment: *"Here is some code:"* You just added data but forgot to paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `eval_keys` dictionary is problematic because it contains many identical keys. As soon as the program is compiled, all the duplicates will be removed, and only one key, value pair for each unique key will be kept. It should be constructed in the opposite way, with the tuple values as keys and the letter strings as values. Additionally, all of your functions have unnecessary parameters that are not used, and you have some redundant castings to int and str. Now in order to convert each list of tuples in `answer_all` into a string of 6 letters, you can map the elements to `eval_keys` and join them.

```
import random

def rand_participant():
    #generate a single random participant
    age = random.randint(28,35)
    gender = random.choice(['male', 'female'])
    return age, gender

def rand_answer():
    #create a single random answer 
    f = random.randint(1,5)
    q = random.randint(1,5)
    return f, q

def participant_answer(): 
    # create all 6 random answers
    all_answer = [rand_answer() for blu in range(6)]
    return all_answer

def survey_res():
    # create set of random survery results
    result = [participant_answer() for bla in range(101)]
    return result

#generate a list of 100 random participants
sample_probe = [rand_participant() for _ in range(101)]
my_survey = list(zip(sample_probe, survey_res()))
answer_all = list(survey_res())

eval_keys = {
    (1,1): "Q",  (1,2): "A",  (1,3): "A",  (1,4): "A",  (1,5): "P", 
    (2,1): "R",  (2,2): "Q",  (2,3): "I",  (2,4): "I",  (2,5): "M", 
    (3,1): "R",  (3,2): "I",  (3,3): "I",  (3,4): "I",  (3,5): "M", 
    (4,1): "R",  (4,2): "I",  (4,3): "I",  (4,4): "Q",  (4,5): "M", 
    (5,1): "R",  (5,2): "R",  (5,3): "R",  (5,4): "R",  (5,5): "Q"
}

answers = [''.join(map(lambda x: eval_keys[x], ans)) for ans in answer_all]
print(answers)
```